# Detect iphone region

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phone-number, region

In my app, the user is supposed to insert a phone number, which is then displayed somewhere else.

In the contacts application, when displaying a phone number, it automatically appears in the format of the language selected by the user.

Is there a way to do this automatically, or a way to detect the region and then adapt the displayed string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSLocale for getting that type of information.

```
[NSLocale currentLocale];
```

Check the documentation for further information:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html